# Upload scene layer package to ArcGIS Online and show all features

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-pro, scene-layer-package

I am currently working in Arcgis Pro 1.4.1, creating scene layer packages. I successfully created a package of one layer that consists of 35,000 points. However, when opening it in a scene viewer in ArcGIS Online it will only show a few random points. Zooming in and out gives me more points and a better view but still the points are shown rather random. Some points that are in front of other points pop up later than others.

I already tried to upload a package with only 2,000 points but this gives the same effect. I also tried to upload points through a hosted webscene but than I am limited to 2,000 points.

Does anyone know how to upload all the 35,000 points to a scene viewer, showing all of the points, or at least the most prominent ones first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the point scene layer uses auto-thinning, right now there is no way to define the thinning on the layer. We are working towards increasing the allowed feature limit so feature layers with more than 2000 records which will come in a future release to ArcGIS Online. If you just want to show basic shape you could convert the points to multipatch and create a 3DObject scene layer and see if that gives you an output that suits your scene better. http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/buffer-3d.htm